# Cannot resolve method valueof(java.math.BigDecimal)

Tags: java

My code looks like:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String response : allResponses) {
     if(frequencyMap.containsKey(response)) {
         frequencyMap.put(response,BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0));
     }else{
         BigDecimal value= BigDecimal.valueOf(frequencyMap.get(response)); //error
         // have to increment the value here
         frequencyMap.replace(response, value);
     }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Cannot resolve method valueof(java.math.BigDecimal)
```

But the value frequencyMap.get(response) is of type BigDecimal only. How do I resolve this?

Comment: `frequencyMap.get(response)` already returns BigDecimal because thats how you've declared your map. Why do you wnat to convert it to `BigDecimal` using `BigDecimal.valueOf()` once more?

Comment: Directly do :`BigDecimal value= frequencyMap.get(response);`

Comment: frequencyMap.get(response) is BigDecimal, so you don't need to convert it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks everyone. This solved it.